# How to replace one html element with another

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace a form inside a div with jQuery, consider following html:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="some text here" id="friendship" class="not_friends">
  </form>
</div>
```

and following js code:

```
div = $("#friendship.not_friends").parent().parent();
$("form", div).remove();
$(div).add(response);
```

the "form" element is removed, as I want, but the new form (in 'response' string) isn't added to div, why ?
and there's a better way to write this js code ? this looks not good for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

jQuery has built in functionality for replacing one element with another.

See: `.replaceWith()`

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

```
$("form").replaceWith(response);
```

Comment: wow this function simplifies things a lot, JS `$("#friendship.not_friends").parent().replaceWith(response);` . Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append)/[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)

```
$(div).append(response);
```

[.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add) returns a new jQuery object with the current object and the objects returned by the selector passed

Answer (score 1):

1- give an Id to the div

2- use this to replace the content of div :

$("#divId").html("your response Content");